# How far is the open source software stack from real AMR product?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I can see open source robot solution (e.g., ros,opentcs...) and can search the chipset for demo robot, but I am doing industry mobile robot and thinking how far such kind of software from real-life product ?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/417583/how-far-is-the-open-source-software-stack-from-real-amr-product-?/) by [FengxianEric](https://answers.ros.org/users/163911/fengxianeric/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2023-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are hundreds of robotics companies using this open source stack for their products. Look no further than the sponsors of ROSCon, folks on navigation.ros.org's robot's using page, or any number of other documents.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2023-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FengxianEric](https://answers.ros.org/users/163911/fengxianeric/) on 2023-07-24**:
Thanks support, in product view what is key advantages and disadvantages between ros1 and ros2 sw stack ?